# Change the selected value in a drop down using jQuery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have to assign the value in a repeater column in such a way that upon assignment, the value in the repeater column becomes the current selection in the drop down.

I have the correct value to assign in `$('#myname_' + rowIndex).text()`, but when I assign this value to the id.value of the dropdown - as shown below - the assignment has no effect. What am I doing wrong.

```
$("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_myname").value = $('#myname_' + rowIndex).text();
```

Comment: is `$("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_myname")` a `<select>` element? If so, you need to use `val()`, not `text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_myname").val($('#myname_' + rowIndex).text());
```

Or

```
 $("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_myname")[0].value = $('#myname_' + rowIndex).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses `val()`, JavaScript (the HTML DOM object) uses `value`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `val` function instead?

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_myname").val($('#myname_' + rowIndex).text());
```

The `val` function can be used to get the value from the object if you use it without parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_myname").val($('#myname_' + rowIndex).text())
```

or

```
$("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_myname")[0].value = $('#myname_' + rowIndex).text()
```